# Integrating $\ln{(x^2+1)}$ by splitting into $\ln{(x+i)}$ and $\ln{(x-i)}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Using u-sub I was able to integrate it into $$x(\ln{(x^2+1)}-2)+i\ln(\frac{x+i}{x-i})+C$$
Simplifying the end part I got $$i\ln(\frac{x+i}{x-i})=i\ln\Bigl(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+i(\frac{2x}{x^2+1})\Bigr)$$
Using Euler's Formula we can simplify further $$\begin{aligned}i\ln\Bigl(\frac{x^2-1}{x^2+1}+i(\frac{2x}{x^2+1})\Bigr)&=i\ln(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta) \\ &=i(i\theta) \\ &=-\arctan\Bigl(\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\Bigr)\end{aligned}$$
This differs greatly from the result we would obtain if we just integrated normally, which is $$\begin{aligned}x(\ln{(x^2+1)}-2)+2\arctan x+C\end{aligned}$$

As you can probably tell I was just messing around at first but then I thought this was quite interesting, so I am wondering if an integral like this cannot be evaluated this way, or somewhere in my steps I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\tan2\theta=\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta}$$
so your formulas do agree.

Comment: Oh wow, it didn't even occur to me that I can use this identity, thanks! Not sure how this would help in my A levels at all though